# firefox mobile autoplay muted

Tags: html, firefox, html5-video

I dont know why but firefox mobile is not understanding that i am telling it to play the video muted. "Autoplay is only allowed when approved by the user, the site is activated by the user, or media is muted." is the message i keep getting. I tried doing it like this and still does not work

```
  ` var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.muted = true;
vid.autoplay = true;
vid.loop = true;
vid.load();
});`
```

And i tried the simpliest way of doing it which was

`<video autoplay muted loop ></video>`

Both of those work fine in Edge and chrome which are the ones i keep playing with. It also works fine on firefox desktop. The problem is just firefox mobile. Which btw i have spent a whole day and a bit more just fixing stuff on my website just so it works with firefox mobile, its such an annoying browser at this point. Anyone know a way of getting the autoplay to work on firefox mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can have multiple reasons behind it.
I have just worked with the YouTube API last month and a problem I had was that autoplay was not working because I told my browser to block autoplay on all videos. So changed a lot of code before I remember that the settings of my own browser were the reason my project was not working.

I had two things to fix to make my project work:

- The browser could have been set (by default or by the user or by a
  plugin) to block autoplay on videos. So that needs to be taken into consideration.
- Another one could be the phone itself; it could have been set to not autoplay videos and music to save on Credit when not connected to wifi.

Comment: you are right, it was the browser! Firefox mobile comes by default with block to autoplay and audio.