# How to play sound when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to play a sound when the page loads

```html
<audio src="song.mp3">
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

What is the easiest way to do it?
I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
        document.getElementById("my_audio").play();  
    }
</script>
```

but browser console says `"*Autoplay* is only allowed when approved by the user, the site is activated by the user, or media is muted."`

Comment: <audio src="song.mp3" id="my_audio" loop="loop" ></audio>                                   <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("my_audio").play();
  }
</script>   but still is not working browser console says "Autoplay is only allowed when approved by the user, the site is activated by the user, or media is muted."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Browser denying javascript play()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57504122/browser-denying-javascript-play)

Comment: You can't do it, it's forbidden, because it's annoying

Comment: Does this answer your question? [firefox mobile autoplay muted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67962345/firefox-mobile-autoplay-muted)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a iframe to autoplay music.

When the user has allowed auto play from a specific website the iframe should auto play the music as expected.

```
<iframe height="0" width="0" allow="autoplay" src="happy.mp3"></iframe>
```

In case, you want to autoplay using the `audio` tag use can use this snippet:

```
<audio autoplay loop src="happy.mp3"></audio>
```